# How in C# can I tell if a JPEG image is progressive

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, encoding, jpeg

A JPEG can be either encoded in different ways; Base Line, Progressive etc.

How can I determine if progressive was used in C#

Comment: Actually, it can be encoded in several other ways. Sequential is very common. Then there are the less common JPEG modes.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the HTML version http://techslides.com/demos/progressive-test.html a JPEG that is encoded progressively contains the bytes FFC2.

The [FFC2 marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) shows the start of frame that is only present in progressive images.

```
var imageUrl = "progress.jpg";

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
   byte[] imageBytes = wc.DownloadData(imageUrl);

   string hex = BitConverter.ToString(imageBytes.Take(500).ToArray());
   var imageAsHex = hex.Replace("-", "").ToUpper();

   Console.WriteLine("Is JPEG: " + imageAsHex.Contains("FFD8"));
   Console.WriteLine("Is Progressive: " + imageAsHex.Contains("FFC2"));
}
```

Comment: Why would you convert the bytes to string though? That is so horribly inefficient, and it can cause something like bytes "AF FD 8B" to be wrongly seen as match for "FF D8". Also, seems like a more accurate method than "a 2-byte sequence exists somewhere in the first 500 bytes" could be used.

Comment: Well, either actually figure out how the jpeg header works and detect it correctly, or just loop through the bytes and check them in sequences of 2 to detect your properties. Sure it'll be more code on your side, but I'm fairly sure it'll still be more efficient than string comparisons. The fact string tools are a short way of getting a result doesn't mean there's not a lot more going on behind these simple calls.